# How to update a Dynamics CRM 4.0 custom property within an IPlugin context

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-4

I'm dealing with a custom (extended) property of a default Entity (`email`) within a plug-in context and despite the approach works for creation (`.Add()`) it does not for updates (nor is an `.Update()` method associated). Here´s the actual code:

```
public class EmailPreCreateHandler : IPlugin
{
        DynamicEntity dynamicEntity;

        if (context.InputParameters.Properties.Contains("Target")
            && context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"] is DynamicEntity)
        {
            dynamicEntity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];

            if (dynamicEntity.Name != EntityName.email.ToString()) { return; }
        }
        else { return; }

        try
        {
            if (dynamicEntity.Properties.Contains("new_property1")
                || dynamicEntity.Properties.Contains("new_property2"))
            {
                var new_property3 = new CrmBooleanProperty("new_property3", new CrmBoolean(true));
                dynamicEntity.Properties.Add(new_property3);
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException exception)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(
                "An error occurred with the plug-in.", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if I should do something like this to make it work?

```
dynamicEntity.Properties.Remove(new_property3);
dynamicEntity.Properties.Add(new_property3);
```

Registration details

**(Assembly)**

- Location: Database

**(Step)**

- Message: Create
- Primary Entity: email
- Secondary Entity: none
- Filtering Attributes: All Attributes
- Run in User's Context: Calling User
- Execution Order: 1
- Eventing Pipeline Stage of Execution: Pre Stage

I will really appreciate any feedback. Thanks much in advance,

Comment: What's about registration? Pre/Post? Which message?

Comment: @ckeller: thanks for the contribution - I've updated the post with the plugin registration details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you would add/update `new_property3` if either `new_property1` or `new_property2` are present.

```
if (dynamicEntity.Properties.Contains("new_property1") || dynamicEntity.Properties.Contains("new_property2"))
{
  dynamicEntity["new_property3"] = new CrmBoolean(true);
}
```

If you access `dynamicEntity["new_property3"]` for ***write*** access it will either create the property, if it does not exist or overwrite the existing value.

Comment: Thanks much for the contribution - your sample code is indeed better expressing the concept of create/overwrite - I'm definitely refactoring the implementation using your approach.

Comment: @Nano you're welcome. I've your are interested in Dynamics CRM topics, take a look at the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics-crm?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2)